# Retrieve data from MS Access Database Horizontally

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Here is the image of my data base

[image: MS Acess DB]

My plan is to Chose what process will be included on the combobox based on partnumberpartname column.

example

I will chose the PartNumberPartName(Column) from a combobox named "PartsList"
"184384300-FRAME , RWP; PH (H901)"

then all the data alongside with it from Process1 column to process4 column should show on another combobox name "Process", it must contains
'Combobox(Process)

'Item1 = Machining

'Item2 = Washing

'Item3 = Deburring / Visual Inspection

'Item4 = FG

Is it possible or do I need to find another way to store the datas.

I would like to this on vb.net visual studio

Thank you.

I hope this clear example.

Comment: Of course it's possible and you would do it exactly as you would expect. There's no magic to it. Once you select a record, you get the four values from those four columns and put them in a list, then load that list into the `ComboBox`.

Comment: thanks sir. I was just thinking if there's other way around. I used that method in one of my projects but Thanks!

Comment: You could probably use a pivot but I'm not sure that it would be worth it for such a simple scenario.